# How to replace image in ViewPager at specific position

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am making a simple image editing app in which user can choose maximum 3 images from gallery and then all 3 images will be displayed in viewPager and next user will press on pencil icon which is on image and then that particular image will be opened in EditActivity and there user will add some text and press done to save text and last n user will press save button to save that image in Mobile storage and path of that edited image will be passed back to viewPager in MainActivity to display updated image and only problem i am facing is to show that edited image in viewPager. Images which are getting from gallery are stored in `ArrayList<Image> images` variable. I tried my best to find solution Thank you in advance!

library to pick multiple images -> https://github.com/darsh2/MultipleImageSelect

library to edit Images -> https://github.com/burhanrashid52/PhotoEditor

In below method which is in MainActivity I am receiving 3 images from gallery and stored in ArrayList variable and then I am passing it to viewPager adapter and I am able to show these images in viewPager successfully.

MainActivity.java

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
                stringBuilder.append(images.get(i).path).append("\n");
            }

            viewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new viewPagerAdapter(this, images);
            viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        }
    }
```

After this when I click edit icon which is place on image in viewPager(MainActivity) then the particular image and image position will b passed to EditActivity via intent and after editing image will be saved on phone storage and path will b passed back to MainActivity

EditActivity.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(EditActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("ImagePath",filePath);
            i.putExtra("EditPosition",position);
            startActivity(i);
```

(facing problem here)
Again in MainActivity I am retreiving data from intent and trying to replace that image in ArrayList and passing path back to viewPagerAdapter for showing edited image but it doesn't work activity just reloads and nothing happens.

MainActivity.java - onCreate Method

```
  //getting path and position of edited Image back from EditActivity
     String imagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("ImagePath");
     imagePosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("EditPosition",0);

if (imagePath != null) {

            Image image = new Image(0,"",imagePath,false);

            images.remove(imagePosition);
            images.set(imagePosition,image);
            viewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new viewPagerAdapter(this, images);
            viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(this, "image " + image.path,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Model class of MultiImageSelect library

```
image.java
package com.darsh.multipleimageselect.models;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

/**
 * Created by Darshan on 4/18/2015.
 */
public class Image implements Parcelable {
    public long id;
    public String name;
    public String path;
    public boolean isSelected;

    public Image(long id, String name, String path, boolean isSelected) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.path = path;
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(id);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(path);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Image> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Image>() {
        @Override
        public Image createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Image(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Image[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Image[size];
        }
    };

    private Image(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readLong();
        name = in.readString();
        path = in.readString();
    }
}
```

save button code

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.edit_save){
            //saving edited image on Mobile storage
            takeSS(editImage);

            //passing edited image path and position to MainActivity back
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra("ImagePath",filePath);
            i.putExtra("EditPosition",position);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        start = findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        preview = findViewById(R.id.btnPreview);
        audio = findViewById(R.id.btn_audio);
        showAudio = findViewById(R.id.txt_audio);

        ImageView photoView = findViewById(R.id.imgLauncher);
        testimage = findViewById(R.id.testImage);


        //getting path and position of edited Image back from EditActivity
        //imagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("ImagePath");
        //imagePosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("EditPosition",0);


        //Library default method to select image from gallery
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlbumSelectActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_LIMIT, 3);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
                stringBuilder.append(images.get(i).path).append("\n");
            }

            //textView.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
            viewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new viewPagerAdapter(this, images);
            viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        } else if (requestCode == com.starmoonsolutions.image2video.Constants.REQUEST_CODE_EDIT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "yessss", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String imagePath = data.getStringExtra("ImagePath");
            int editPosition = data.getIntExtra("EditPosition", 0);


            Image image = new Image(0, "", imagePath, false);
            images.remove(editPosition);
            images.add(editPosition, image);
            viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }


    }
```

editbutton code in viewPagerAdapter

```
//passing ImagePath & position to EditActivity for editing
        editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = imagesArray.get(position).name;
                String path1 = imagesArray.get(position).path;
                Toast.makeText(context,name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(context,EditActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("Path",path1);
                i.putExtra("position",position);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

when i choose multiple image

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.abc.image2video, PID: 25326
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=10101, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.abc.image2video/com.abc.image2video.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.abc.image2video.viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4284)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4327)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1624)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.abc.image2video.viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
        at com.abc.image2video.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:238)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4327) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1624) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

when i choose single image

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.abc.image2video, PID: 25665
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=10101, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.abc.image2video/com.abc.image2video.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4284)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4327)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1624)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:427)
        at com.abc.image2video.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:237)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4327) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1624) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: That's because you are creating a new instance of MainActivity class. On edit button startActivityForResult for EditActivity and after successful editing send the result back to BaseActivity and handle the result in onResultAcitivty method os MainActivity.

Comment: You need to call startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity() and in EditActivity simply call setResult() after successfully editing. and pass image as argument to the setResult().

Comment: i tried with startActivityForResult bt not working plss see i added more codes

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong here

> viewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new viewPagerAdapter(this, images);
>               viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

you are creating a new Adapter but not going to set to `ViewPager`

and the right path to do this is, if you are going to `EditActivty` from `MainActivity`, than in `save button's onClickListener` why you again open `MainActivity`

just do this in `save button's onClickListener` of `EditActivity`

**EDIT**

> EditActivity.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(EditActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("ImagePath",filePath);
i.putExtra("EditPosition",position);
startActivity(i);
```

remove above lines from `EditActivity`

and paste these lines

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("ImagePath",filePath);
i.putExtra("EditPosition",position);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
finish()
```

and handle result in `onActivityResult()` in MainActivity and just change the list of `images` and notify adapter,

add this code to `onActivityResult` of `MainActivity`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
                stringBuilder.append(images.get(i).path).append("\n");
            }

            viewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new viewPagerAdapter(this, images);
            viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        } else if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_EDIT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            String imagePath = data.getStringExtra("ImagePath","");
            int imagePosition = data.getIntExtra("EditPosition",0);

            Image image = new Image(0,"",imagePath,false);
            images.remove(imagePosition);
            images.set(imagePosition,image);
            viewPagerAdapter.notifyDatSetChnaged();
       }
    }
```

in `Constants.java` add this line

```
public static int REQUEST_CODE_EDIT_IMAGE = 10101;
```

Comment: that intent is declared in save button's onClickListener in EditActivity not in onBackPress() and onActivityResult is already defined in MainActivity pls see above then what changes i need to do in onActivityResult and also images.add(int index,Image element) it takes these arguments that is why i also pasted Image.java model class

Comment: not working still reloading whole activity and Constants.REQUEST_CODE is coming but not Constants.REQUEST_CODE_EDIT_IMAGE  and also i have to write this if(requestCode) under previous if code block which is already there?

Comment: You have to make your own Constants.REQUEST_CODE_EDIT_IMAGE variable in Constant file > i have to write this if(requestCode) under previous if code block which is already there? yes

Comment: i tried but same problem is coming activity reloading when i press save button

Comment: is your `onCreate()` calling again when you come back to `MainActivity`? it should not happen now, Please update your Question show me save button's click, or log you find which says that it's reloading

Comment: added save button code pls check save button is in actionbar

Comment: remove `startActivity(i);` line

Comment: now activity not reloading but it also not navigating back to mainactivity

Comment: show me `MainActivity` where you start `EditActivity`

Comment: pls ma'am check added MainActivity and also added editbutton onClickListener method code which is in viewpageradapter class

Comment: change `context.startActivity(i);` to `context.startActivityForResult(i, Constants.REQUEST_CODE_EDIT_IMAGE);` in edit button click

Comment: nope now again activity is reloading & there is no log error thats y i am nt mentioning abt log errors

Comment: have you remove `startActivity(i);` before `finish()` on save button click?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=10101, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.starmoonsolutions.image2video/com.starmoonsolutions.image2video.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 -> pointing to   ->        images.set(editPosition, image);

Comment: please paste full stack trace